# Lucene Migration from 2 to 7

Tags: lucene

I am migrating Lucene from 2.0 to 7.0. Not able to find out an alternative for ChainedFilter in the latest Lucene Version. Can you please help me migrate.

I have used BooleanQuery.Builder() for migrating from the filter to query, but my use case is a little bit different here. 
Below is my old code that needs to be migrated.

```
        Filter filter = null;
        ArrayList filters = new ArrayList();            
    BooleanQuery filterQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        filterQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(TEXT_FIELD,"0")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        Filter moduleFilter = new QueryWrapperFilter(filterQuery);
        filters.add(moduleFilter);

        BooleanQuery filterQuery2 = new BooleanQuery();
        filterQuery2.add(new TermQuery(new Term(TEXT_FIELD2,"0")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        Filter moduleFilter2 = new QueryWrapperFilter(filterQuery2);
        filters.add(moduleFilter2);

        if ((filters!=null) && (filters.size()>0)){
            Filter []filterArray = new Filter[filters.size()];
            filter = new ChainedFilter((Filter[])filters.toArray(filterArray), ChainedFilter.OR);
        }
```

I have made below changes to upgrade from the filter to query.

```
    Query filter = null;
    ArrayList filters = new ArrayList();

    BooleanQuery.Builder booleanQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    booleanQueryBuilder.add(new TermQuery(new Term(TEXT_FIELD,"0")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    Query moduleFilter = booleanQueryBuilder.build();
    filters.add(moduleFilter);

    BooleanQuery.Builder booleanQueryBuilder2 = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    booleanQueryBuilder2.add(new TermQuery(new Term(TEXT_FIELD2,"0")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    Query moduleFilter2 = booleanQueryBuilder2.build();
    filters.add(moduleFilter2);

    if ((filters!=null) && (filters.size()>0)){
            Query []filterArray = new Query[filters.size()];
            filter = new ChainedQuery((Filter[])filters.toArray(filterArray), ChainedFilter.OR);
    }
```

I believe my above changes are correct but not understanding how to change ChainedFilter.

Answer (score 0):

Filters have been replaced with Queries now, so you would just want to use `BooleanQuery`s.

You will probably want to replace the ChainedFilter with one BooleanQuery, and then add that with `BooleanClause.Occur.FILTER` to another boolean query containing the rest of your query.  Something like:

```
BooleanQuery filter = BooleanQuery.Builder()
    .Add(new TermQuery(new Term('field1', 'filter1')), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
    .Add(new TermQuery(new Term('field2', 'filter2')), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT)
    .build();

BooleanQuery query = BooleanQuery.Builder()
    .Add(filter, BooleanClause.Occur.FILTER)
    .Add(someOtherQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
    .build();
```

---

Relevant notes on these changes:
Removal of ChainedFilter in Lucene 5.0: https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/MIGRATE.html
Removal of Filter in Lucene 6.0: https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/MIGRATE.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.
I tried responding to your comment but StackOverflow did not let me enter more characters. So I have edited the question as a response. Can you please check.